# RecyclerView image caching race conditionn

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I'm getting the wrong image in a recycler view that shows images from the web.
My hypothesis is as follows:

let's say the recyclerview loads image `A` from the web into cell `A'` which is an `ImageView` using Picasso (or glide etc.)
Before the image is loaded, the user scrolls down, and cell `A'` scrolls out of the screen and is being recycled. Now it should show Image `B` that happens to be cached and therefore loads instantly from memory.
Then the web request for image `A` returns, and Picasso sets this image into `ImageView A'`, overriding the correct image `B`

Am I missing something? How would you overcome this?

Comment: I think you should define a data structure, like an `ArrayList` that holds your images, then when the image is loaded from the web put it in the arraylist and notify the adapter.

Comment: I have no experience with picasso. But i guess, a library that popular would provide significant callbacks. If so, use the callbacks to know when images are downloaded and take action. Take into consideration methods involving scrolling of RecyclerView.